# C# repeating a mp3 file once it has finished

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, mp3, repeat

In my current project, i have music that plays depending on the gamestate. Like most games, once the soundtrack ends it then repeats. I'd like to implement such feature into my game so it automatically plays however i'm uncertain where i'd start.

The code/algorithm must acknowledge the fact that the soundtrack has ended and repeat baring in mind that it also will have more code connected to it once i create the gamesettings and sounds sub menu where the user is able to change the sounds etc. This is what i have so far:

```
static public WindowsMediaPlayer Introthemetune = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

public LaunchScreen()
{
    this.Opacity = 0;
    InitializeComponent();
    Introthemetune.URL = "Finalised Game Soundtrack.mp3";
}
```

Comment: Game frameworks have these kinds of capabilities built-in, as well as more interesting features like transitioning from one piece of music to another depending on the state of game play.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay so how do i do it. Not able to use other frameworks other than the .NET framework at the moment as i can't install them on my schools computers

Comment: Look into handling the `PlayerStateChange` event on the `WindowsMediaPlayer`? I assume that is from `WMPLib.dll`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways,

**1. Subscribe to PlayStateChange Event**

You would need to subscribe to `PlayStateChange event` and check the `NewState`

```
Introthemetune.PlayStateChange += Introthemetune_PlayStateChange;

private void Introthemetune_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
  if(e.newState == 8)
  {
    // Play Again
  }
}
```

You can read more on the different play states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WMP/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange)

**2. Set Loop Mode.**

The most easiest approach would be to set the loop mode.

```
Introthemetune.settings.setMode("loop", true);
Introthemetune.URL = "Finalised Game Soundtrack.mp3";
```

This would ensure the track is played repeated continuously.